# Is it possible to have a TCP/IP network using bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, linux, wi-fi

I have my Android U8220 and I need to have a network with my laptop as if it was an ad-hoc wifi connection (tcp/ip). Is that even possible? If you want to know, I'm using `bluez` as manager in my Linux box.

**EDIT**

To clear doubts, I'll be more specific. There's a music program in my laptop called **mpd**. It is controlled by different clients in the network. One of this clients is in my Android and it works perfectly when I'm connected to the wi-fi network in my house.

I wanted to make a direct connection with my laptop, without the need of a router, so there are 2 options:

- Ad-Hoc, which is not available for my phone (I don't know why)
- Bluethooth which is the last option.

[This is the link of the player, for those who want to know](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) (although it doesn't have to much to do with the question.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about using your mobile phone as a tethering device over Bluetooth then sure this is:

[PdaNet](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.pdanet)

[image: PdaNet QR Code]

> Is Linux (Ubuntu etc.) supported?
>
> Meanwhile only Bluetooth DUN is
>   supported (requires android 2.0) on
>   Linux.
>
> We are working on a linux port for USB
>   Tether but it may take a while.
>
> via [junefabrics.com](http://junefabrics.com)

**EDIT**

Sorry for misunderstanding you. Could any of the [following MPD control applications on the Android Market](http://market.android.com/search?q=MPD) help you?

Comment: Please, read **EDITS**

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP and Bluetooth are different protocols. Although, technically this would be WiFi vs Bluetooth. A WiFi device (which uses TCP/IP) cannot communicate with a Bluetooth device, they essentially speak different languages.

It would be possible to have an application on your phone and computer which communicate via bluetooth and then the computer side could then send the necessary commands to the music player. You'd have to develop, or get someone to develop, the apps though.

Comment: To avoid confusion the hypothetical app wouldn't use TCP/IP at any point.

Comment: I've never said I wanted to connect a wifi device with a bluetooth device, even a child would know that's not possible. What I want is the bluetooth of my phone and the bluetooth of my laptop talking to each one, using the upper layer as a TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry. This may help and I guess concludes that you can - http://giovanni.wordpress.com/2007/04/06/how-to-use-tcpip-over-bluetooth/

Comment: That link is very helpful, +1 for that!

Answer (score 2):

According to the OSI model, you can use any transfer protocol in any medium. So, it is possible. In fact, the standard transfer protocol for bluetooth is very similar to TCP.
Anyhow, I can't find any Android application able to do it.